# View with Taxonomy Path

Tags: views, 8, nodes, path-aliases

We have a taxonomy vocab called Phones that goes like this.

Taxonomy: Phones

-Nokia
--3310
--Jitterbug
--7.1
-Samsung
--Galaxy S6
--Galaxy Edge
--**S7**
-HTC
-- one
--**S7**
list goes on, but you get the idea.

We also have content types:
-Questions 
-Photos

in each of these content types, we add taxonomy PHONE as a field.

The view that we are looking to create needs to show the corresponding content type for each phone based on path.

Which means that if we go to 
domain/phone/samsung/s7/questions/

one sees all the questions for the Galaxy S7 but if we go to:

domain/phone/samsung/s7/photos/

one will see all the photos for the Galaxy S7.

How can this view be setup? Especially the path? So that when you go to another 
phone /questions or /photos it still works.

*** BONUS QUESTION ***  There are cases where the same model name is used by two phone manufacturers, for example S7 above.  Is it possible to somehow filter by term id? Or dobule filter? Meaning you filter with parent name in url, then filter with term name that matches the parent name? This would be ideal, but if we can't filter by term ID, we will edit those duplicate models so that they don't conflict.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this not something a module like TVI wouldn’t cover?

Comment: I am not looking to over ride the existing term page. Instead I am looking to create extra pages that shows specific content type at term-page/content-type.